# SetContentView on footer view not working anymore when inflating layout with a listview in it, going from API 17 to API 21

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an android app with a footer view that inflates other layouts to enable the same buttons on bottom of screen in each layout. It used to work perfectly but now with Android 5 it doesn't work anymore. Seems to only brake when the layout has a ListView in it.  Traced the code and it seems to call the function **onRtlPropertiesChanged** in the Toolbar class, when trying to **setContentView** of footer. I'm not sure why this being called because I am not changing the RTL property. I get a **too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010034** message and then a run time exception that states **android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.widget.Toolbar**

**EDIT**

Heres the footer xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="10"
    android:id="@+id/commonlayout" android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lldata"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9.04"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/red_color" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llfooter"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" >

         <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button3" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

         <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the layout I'm trying to inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp" />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="@string/title_activity1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/Activity1Header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"/>
     <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp" />
     <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Activity1listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout's onCreate function

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 
        // set the view
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
        ViewGroup.inflate(Activity1.this, R.layout.activity1, vg);
```

Footer onCreate function, it fails on setContentView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_footer);
```

And the error log

```
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394): Process: com.user.testapp, PID: 14394
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.user.testapp/com.user.testapp.Activity1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.widget.Toolbar
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.widget.Toolbar
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3489)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3561)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:367)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.user.testapp.Footer.onCreate(Footer.java:34)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at com.user.testapp.Activity1.onCreate(Activity1.java:69)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    ... 10 more
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    ... 27 more
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RtlSpacingHelper.setDirection(boolean)' on a null object reference
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged(Toolbar.java:296)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:13245)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding(ViewGroup.java:6032)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:4558)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4150)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:183)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:179)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    at android.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:175)
02-05 15:04:37.843: E/AndroidRuntime(14394):    ... 30 more
```

Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: If you add some code and describe your problem more clear, it will be very good

Comment: @KirillShalnov ok here some more info

Comment: @VickyWang I'm having the same problem here. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed the problem and it wasn't anywhere near where I was looking.  The problem originated from the custom theme I using for the ListViews.  Previously I had declared the theme in the App Manifest under the appropriate intent declarations, but since in Android Lollipop themes was divided into themes and styles it wasn't propagating correctly.  So I removed the custom theme declaration from the manifest, and set the theme pragmatically in the appropriate onCreate functions and that solved the problem. Thank goodness